# Random Connection Error in Google Cloud Functions (Python)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, xmlhttprequest, google-cloud-functions

Because I have been getting some unexpected CORS errors in my browser console for the past few weeks, I have set up a super simple Python script with a single function inside Google Cloud Functions:

```py
def prepData(request):

    if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
        headers = {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600'
        }
        return ('', 204, headers)

    headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    }
    return ("", 200, headers)
```

It looks very similar to the function presented by Google on their [documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#handling_cors_requests) with one major difference: I am using POST rather than GET.

When calling the function, I am seeing a success message (`Function execution took 13 ms, finished with status code: 200`) in around 50% of cases and a connection error (`Function execution took 11 ms, finished with status: 'connection error'`) in all other cases. Whenever I am getting a connection error inside GCF, Chrome's console logs an error: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

I am currently considering three possible causes:

1. GCP Infrastructure. I have found some related questions where Google was acknowledging some infrastructure issues.
2. Python error
3. CORS error (user sideshowbarker says: very unlikely)

What is the cause of the issue and how do I fix it?

---

Here is the JS code that calls the Python script:

```
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "[URL]");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhr.send(stringified_serialized_data);
```

---

Edit on 4/2/20:

I have discovered a way to **not** trigger the error: Add *some* code between the two return statements. I have not yet figured out what kind of code is needed, but `d = request.get_json()` appears to be sufficient. The new code looks as follows:

```
def prepData(request):

    if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
        headers = {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600'
        }
        return ('', 204, headers)

    d = request.get_json() #THIS LINE IS NEW

    headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    }
    return ("", 200, headers)
```

Comment: This doesn't look like a Cloud Function, which would have a signature like `def function_name(request)`. Can you include the function you've deployed here which calls `prepData` as well?

Comment: @DustinIngram Hm, I don't quite get what you mean. I am currently using the inline editor (https://cloud.google.com/functions/img/qs-python-console.png). Below the code input field, it says "Function to execute," where I added "prepData". I could easily rename that function and also rename the request parameter. That said, it has worked like that for about a year.

Comment: Got it, I think the `json_data` variable name threw me off. This variable is actually a request, not just JSON data.

Comment: Understood, thanks! That also explains why json_data.method has a value. I will look into this and change the parameter name for clarification. I assume, however, that it has nothing to do with the main issue described above.

Comment: You can safely rule out CORS as a possible cause. The CORS configuration shown in the question can in no way ever be causing a connection error. So in general, CORS isn’t relevant to the problem. The only reason the browser is logging that CORS message when you get a connection error is that the response the browser is getting in that case doesn’t have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header — but that’s normal and expected. No response for a connection-error case is ever gonna have an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE**

After digging further, we realized that the problem is actually a bug in the Google Cloud Function service. This bug affects specifically cloud functions using the Python runtime. Those functions will raise a *connection error* (and will return code 500) if they get an HTTP POST request with a body larger than ~10 KB. Interestingly though, this won't happen in every request with such characteristics, but in most of them.

The Google support service was informed about this issue and they acknowledged the bug. They created [a public issue in their issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149753461) that should be updated with additional information according to the progress of the solution. By the day of this writing the issue is marked as "New".

Workaround: as suggested by @Timon, it seems that calling `request.get_json()` in the function seems to fix the issue for requests with JSON bodies. This won't work if the body of your request uses a different format.

---

**OLD ANSWER**

I just set up a clean GC Function with the exact same code you provided and it worked flawlessly. I can make requests through the browser (using your JS code) and they never fail.

This leave us with two options:

1. There is something in your browser or your internet connection that is causing some of your requests to fail.
2. There is something in your GCF that is causing errors.

For option 1 check this:

- Do the failed requests occur in batches? Or they are randomly sampled? If they occur in batches the problem could be your internet connection.
- Are you using some sort of VPN or proxy? Try disabling it.
- Have you tried multiple browsers? If not, try. Is the described behaviour the same in all of them?

For option 2, check this:

- Is your function the exact same code you published? If not, and it has more code, the problem is probably there.
- Do you deploy your function using some command line tool? Is yes, try to do it through the inline editor in GCP website.
- In the networking setting of your function (in advanced settings), be sure to select "Allow all traffic"

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me debug the code/setup! While going through your answer, I did learn what "caused" the issue: the stringified JSON object I am parsing to the function. I played around with it a little bit and was able to force errors when calling your function by parsing JSON object large enough (>100KB will get you an error almost every time, but 50KB or so is sufficient); you should see connection error warnings on your side. I am probably missing something here. Is there a limit I am exceeding? According to this page, I should be fine: https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas

Comment: Wow, it seems you discovered a bug in the Google Cloud Platfom: POST request with a body larger than 50KB fail sometimes. It doesn't matter if the requests are made through the browser, using Postman I got the same error. It isn't a memory issue in the function either. I finally discovered that the problem is related to their Python 3.7 runtime, because this doesn't happen if you use Node runtime instead. I contacted the technical support team and they should provide an answer soon.

Comment: Have you heard back from Google by any chance? I have tried reaching out to them, but they weren't helpful at all. Currently considering switching to AWS Lambda.

Comment: I have been emailing with the support service but they are quite slow. Three days ago they told me the issue was passed to the Cloud Function engineering team. In the meanwhile you may try to use the Node runtime (not Python though) or switch to AWS Lambda as you suggested.

Comment: I have made an edit to the post. Adding code (e.g., `d = request.get_json()`) seems to fix the error. I was able to reliably get **no** connection errors on my side even with a body larger than 750KB. I would be super grateful if you could give it a shot on your side.

Comment: @Timon I can confirm that using `request.get_json()` fixes the issue for me, but only for requests using JSON format though. I updated the answer with this information and the link to the issue tracker I got from the support service.

Comment: I was able to fix this for a request that didn't have a json body. I just needed to print the response from the request. Before I was not using the response at all. This makes me suspect that the bug is caused by the way Cloud Functions handle request futures. The function may not know how to handle a future that is never forced to resolve/waited for.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by increasing the RAM allocated to the Cloud Function. Mine had 512MB when this issue was occurring. I increased it to 1GB and it started working like a charm.