# Google Cloud Functions throw "connection error" on Python background functions

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Google Cloud Functions throws "connection errors" randomly since yesterday. We had this error couple of months ago and without a fix, it just disappeared after we redeployed the same code.

Even the previous version of code which never had any issue or error has the "connection errors" now.

[image]

Runtime: Python 3.7
Memory: Usually 512MB We tried 2GB as well.
Triggers by Pub/Sub message.

requirements.txt

```
google-cloud-datastore==1.7.3
google-cloud-pubsub==0.39.1
influxdb==5.2.3
pandas==0.24.2
numpy==1.19.2
googleads==23.0.1
croniter==0.3.30
sendgrid==6.1.1
oauth2client==4.1.3
gspread==3.2.0
requests==2.22.0
pyarrow==0.17.0
google-cloud-core==1.3.0
google-cloud-storage==1.23.0
google-cloud-logging==1.15.0
pydantic==1.6.1
```

Based on some answers on the same error on nodejs. It's fixed by updating to the recent runtime of node. So, we are trying to update to python 3.9 with updated python modules as well.

Has anyone faced the same problem in Python 3.7 and knows how to fix it?

Comment: Can you describe more what type of connection your Cloud Function do? I'm seeing Google Cloud communication product, influxdb, Pandas,... What are you doing in your function?

Comment: You might wanna read through this stackoverflow question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60640852/random-connection-error-in-google-cloud-functions-python?rq=1 the OP of this question has edited his question to add the answer as well. Also there is an answer which will point you to an issue tracker which you might wanna look at.

Comment: Also is the function getting invoked and executed? Or are you connecting to something inside the function which is resulting in the error? You can try printing something at the start of the function so that we can get to know if the problem is with the function invocation or something else. Can you please provide the complete error in case it's incomplete?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere The repository has multiple functions hence we have influxdb, pandas etc.  The function which we deployed recently is not using influxdb or pandas.  If there is any connection error on influxdb in any case there will be an exception which will end the function with status as "failed".

Comment: @ZeenathSN in the other question the OP is using HTTP trigger and I am using pubsub. Which can handle relatively larger data during function invocation. But that's still not the case here. We pass an empty json object `{}` that's it.

Comment: @ZeenathSN Today we noticed some functions are executed successfully  some are just "connection error"

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs in Python 3.7 function, when it encounters a logging throughput issue. This throws SIGTERM, which is a signal to terminate, sent by a function or worker and the connection error is observed.
To resolve this issue, it is recommended to either:

1. Reduce logging, or
2. Upgrade to python 3.8 runtime. Python 3.8 doesn’t have this logging throughput issue.

Comment: No, We faced the issue on both python 3.8 and python 3.9

Answer (score 0):

This is weird. The problem has gone after we redeployed the same code yesterday. Seems like something was off in google cloud.

[image: Metrics explorer]